# ng-show not working inside directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show

I would like to do something like this 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2meLx4c/), making the text disappear and reappear with every click.

Problem is, it seem that with an isolated scope you can't have access to the controller scope. I solved it in the link function, handling there click event and setting my "showMe" flag using **scope.$apply**, like:

```
scope.$apply('showMe = false');
```

Is this the right way to go or there is some more elegant method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go (http://jsfiddle.net/66d0t7k0/1/)

Put your click handler in the link function and expose `showMe` to the `scope`

```
app.directive('example', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p ng-show=\"showMe\">Text to show</p><button ng-click=\"clickMe()\">Click me</button>',
        scope: {
            exampleAttr: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.clickMe = function () {
                scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on apairet's answer, since your directive is using an isolated scope, you could handle all of that in the template itself like so:

```
app.directive('example', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p ng-show=\"showMe\">Text to show</p><button ng-init=\"showMe = false\" ng-click=\"showMe = !showMe\">Click me</button>',
        scope: {
            exampleAttr: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope) {

        }
    };
});
```

Another consideration is to use ng-if rather than ng-show as it doesn't render the element in the DOM until the expression evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the scope in the directive by setting scope: false
You can then put all your function in the main controller scope

```
angular.module('appMyApp').directive('appMyAppItem', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'link/to/url',
        controller: 'appMyAppController',
        scope: false
    }
});


angular.module('appMyApp').controller('appMyAppController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.showItem = true;
    $scope.toggleItem = function(){
        $scope.showItem = !$scope.showItem;
    };
}]);
```

Hope this helps